# why the process not run in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

i have a `bot(query, key)` function to post data, `dicts(query, answer)` to wrap the return result, and `query_pipe(query_list)` to process list of query request. But when i put that in `multiprocessing.Process`, i found that `bot(query, key)` return nothing. Here's my code.

```
def bot(query, key):
    data = {
        'key'    : key, 
        'info'   : query, 
        'userid' : 'wechat-robot', 
    }

    try:
        apiUrl = url
        page = requests.post(apiUrl, data=data)
        if page.json()['code'] == '100000':
            answer = page.json()['text']
            return dicts(query, answer)
        else:
            return dicts(query, 'failed')
    except Exception as e: 
            return '500 Error'

def dicts(query, answer):
    return {'query': query, 'answer': answer}

def query_pipe(query_list):

    keys_pool = []
    with open('keys.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            keys_pool.append(line.strip('\n'))

    idx = 0
    print(bot(query_list[0], keys_pool[0]))

p = Process(target=query_pipe, args=(query_data,))
p.start()
p.join()
```

But when i run the `query_pipe(query_list)` which not using `multiprocess.Process`, `query_pipe(query_list)` would print the correct output. I feel so confused, so anyone could give me a hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work in single process?

Comment: @SergeBallesta no, it does not work